# C++ While Loop to work

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop

Since I know the basics of Python (3), I decided to take the programs I did in Python and type them in C++ to get the hang of C++.

**Problem**: When you type "TheEnd" for the name, I wish the program to end, but for some reason if you type "TheEnd" it will ask for the other fields once, and then end. **Is there a way for the user to type "TheEnd" when asked for a name and the program just ends?** (I tried putting the while loop in different areas, but to no avail.)

Here is what I have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

//While loop.

using namespace std;

main()
{

   string name;
   string major;
   float hours, qualityPoints, GPA;

   while (name!="TheEnd") //Here's the while loop

   {
   cout<<"Please enter your name. "<<endl;
   cin>>name;

   cout<<"Please enter your major. "<<endl;
   cin>>major;

   cout<<"List the hours you've completed so far. "<<endl;
   cin>>hours;

   cout<<"List how many quality points you have. "<<endl;
   cin>>qualityPoints;

   GPA = qualityPoints / hours;

   if (GPA >= 3.4 and hours >= 12)

   {

   cout<<name<<endl;
   cout<<major<<endl;
   cout<<"You made the Dean's List."<<endl;
   }

   else

   {

   cout<<"You did not make the Dean's List."<<endl;

   }
}

}
```

Comment: Yes, of course there is. You just need to check the name before asking for other input.

Comment: Curious, how did you write the python program? You would have to check the name regardless python or c++.

Comment: read your code - it is doing exactly what you have written (always true of course, but here its very clear)

Comment: put `if (name == "TheEnd") break;` after `cin>>name`

Comment: @TonyJiang I'm not sure how I would show you the code I used for Python, but it's almost exactly the same as the C++ code I have. (I thought there was a way to send private messages on this site, guess not.)

Comment: @MehrZ Thank you kind sir, this is what I was looking for. :) I wish there was a way to mark your answer as the best answer.....

Comment: @Geos59 if you add the `if`like in MehrZ or my answer, change at least the `while` to a `for(;;)`.

Comment: @MartinSchlott Should I ever use a while loop? Or should I just use 'for' loop for everything?

Comment: @Geos59 No, no. If you have something to count, then use `for`(see an infinite loop as infinite count). If there is a decision to loop which is not bound to something you can count, then use while. Your example is a little misleading here, it is a special case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is asking because your condition is tested at the beginning and then after asking all fields.

The smallest change of your code would be following changes:

```
 for(;;) // Former while(name!="TheEnd")
 {
   cout<<"Please enter your name. "<<endl;
   cin>>name;

   if(name=="TheEnd")
       break;
```

Some explanation:

Usually it is common practice to use `for(;;)` instead of `while(true)` as endless loop. The reason for that lies in the fact the some compiler emit(ted) warnings for constant expressions in if/while (for e.g. [VS 2005](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t66728h(VS.80).aspx) which was AFAIK widely used). In most professional projects warnings are taken as error.

Every loop (for/while) can be exit by using `break`. So you have no loop condition but a exit condition. I decided to wrote this solution because it needed the smallest change to your sample code. Also there is no (easy) way to keep your breaking condition as part of the while condition.

Keep the `while(name!="TheEnd")` and only add the `if` after the `cin` is not good pratice. You produce "cargo cult programming" code with that.

Comment: _"Usually it is common practice to use `for(;;)` instead of `while(true)`"_ Uhm, what? Which makes the significant difference for these? Please elaborate. BTW OP asked for `while (name!="TheEnd")` and not for an infinite loop. Checking the `cin` results afterwards using a `do {} while()` should do that job well.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Some compiler emit(ted) warnings on constant expression in if/while constructions (e.g. VC2005  C4127). BTW `do{} while()`  with checking `cin` forces the user to enter at least  one whole entry. To enter "major","points" and "hour" after you enter "TheEnd" do not look like good practice. Also in my answers I try to change the given code as little as possible. Except the OP ask for that. I will extend my answer.